# Why do Scala parallel collections sometimes cause an OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing

This takes around 1 second

```
(1 to 1000000).map(_+3)
```

While this gives **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

```
(1 to 1000000).par.map(_+3)
```

**EDIT:**

I have standard scala 2.9.2 configuration. I am typing this on scala prompt. And in the bash i can see [ -n "$JAVA_OPTS" ] || JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx256M -Xms32M"

AND i dont have JAVA_OPTS set in my env.

1 million integers = 8MB, 
creating list twice = 16MB

Comment: Can you please add a little more detail here? With how much memory do you start your JVM, any other switches? Do you run this in the REPL or do you compile it? If you run this from the REPL how many instructions have you executed before? I just tried it in my REPL and I executed it 10 times without an OOM.

Comment: Works just fine in my REPEL to.

Comment: @Jan for me it worked fine in the REPL too, but only the first time ...

Comment: For me it works fine. (Several times...)

Comment: On 64bit HotSpot a boxed integer has 24 bytes * 1000000 == 24 MB plus the overhead of the range and the parallel stuff...

Comment: @Christian I checked again. It works twice. The third time it crashes.

Answer (score 9):

It seems definitely related to the JVM memory option **and** to the memory required to stock a Parralel collection. For example:

```
scala> (1 to 1000000).par.map(_+3)
```

ends up with a `OutOfMemoryError` the third time I tried to evaluate it, while

```
scala> (1 to 1000000).par.map(_+3).seq
```

never failed. The issue is not the computation its the storage of the Parrallel collection.

Answer (score 3):

Several reasons for the failure:

1. Parallel collections are not specialized, so the objects get boxed. This means that you can't multiply the number of elements with 8 to get the memory usage.
2. Using `map` means that the range is converted into a vector. For parallel vectors an efficient concatenation has not been implemented yet, so merging intermediate vectors produced by different processors proceeds by copying - requiring more memory. This will be addressed in future releases.
3. The REPL stores previous results - the object evaluated in each line remains in memory.

Comment: Is it possible to make them specialized someday?

Comment: Once the array specialization is implemented, some of the collection types should be specialized, yes.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here, the amount of memory required to store a parallel collection and the amount of memory required to 'pass through' a parallel collection.

The difference can be seen between these two lines:

```
(1 to 1000000).map(_+3).toList
(1 to 1000000).par.map(_+3).toList
```

The REPL stores the evaluated expressions, remember. On my REPL, I can execute both of these 7 times before I run out of memory. Passing via the parallel executions uses extra memory temporarily, but once the toList is executed, that extra usage is garbage collected.

```
(1 to 100000).par.map(_+3)
```

returns a ParSeq[Int] (in this case a ParVector), which takes up more space than a normal Vector. This one I can execute 4 times before I run out of memory, whereas I can execute this:

```
(1 to 100000).map(_+3)
```

11 times before I run out of memory. So parallel collections, if you keep them around will take up more space.

As a workaround, you can transform them into simpler collections like a `List` before you return them.

As for why so much space is taken up by parallel collections and why it keeps references to so many things, I don't know, but I suspect `views`[*], and if you think it's a problem, [raise an issue for it](https://issues.scala-lang.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

[*] without any real evidence.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, but using a ThreadPool seems to get rid of the problem for me:

```
  val threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
  val quadsMinPar = quadsMin.par
  quadsMinPar.tasksupport = new ThreadPoolTaskSupport(threadPool.asInstanceOf[ThreadPoolExecutor])
```

ForkJoin for large collections might be creating too many threads.