# Tuning clojure reducers library performance

Tags: clojure, reducers

Why is mapping/reducing with reducers library has worse performance than normal map/reduce?

```
user=> (time (reduce + (map inc (range 100000000))))
"Elapsed time: 14412.627966 msecs"
5000000050000000

user=> (time (reduce + (r/map inc (range 100000000))))
... (C-c)

user=> (time (r/reduce + (r/map inc (range 100000000))))
....(C-c)
```

I had two kill the later two as it takes indefinitely long. What is wrong here?

**EDIT:**
It seems like other languages also have similar problems. Scala seems to be breaking at a million only. [Why do Scala parallel collections sometimes cause an OutOfMemoryError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847628/why-do-scala-parallel-collections-sometimes-cause-an-outofmemoryerror) . While clojure reducers are faster than normal at a million.

Comment: to make question clearly,which lib are you using?

Comment: @JiacaiLiu clojure.core.reducers, http://clojure.org/reducers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To complement @a-webb's answer, this is a compiler bug and an involved one to really fix. ([See this post for more details.](http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2013/09/11/macros-closures-and-unexpected-object-retention/))

Another way to work around the problem is to use a *fuse*:

```
(defn once-seq
  "Returns a sequence on which seq can be called only once."
  [coll]
  (let [a (atom coll)]
    (reify clojure.lang.Seqable
      (seq [_]
        (let [coll @a]
          (reset! a nil)
          (seq coll))))))
```

and then:

```
=> (time (r/reduce + (r/map inc (once-seq (range 100000000)))))
"Elapsed time: 3692.765 msecs"
5000000050000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Performance is grinding to a halt as memory is being exhausted. If you keep waiting, you would most likely encounter a memory error. Creating a reducer holds the head of the collection in a closure. Thus, the huge lazy-sequence ties up memory as it becomes realized.

Here's what's happening, distilled

```
user=> (def n 100000000)
#'user/n

user=> (time (dorun (range n)))
"Elapsed time: 12349.034702 msecs"
```

Now the same, but from within a closure

```
user=> (defn foo [x] (fn [f] (f x)))
#'user/foo

user=> (time ((foo (range n)) dorun))
OutOfMemoryError GC overhead limit exceeded ... (sometime later)
```

Compare to

```
(time (do (doall (range n)) nil))
OutOfMemoryError GC overhead limit exceeded ... (sometime later)
```

The suspect closure in reducers

```
user=> (source r/folder)
(defn folder
  "Given a foldable collection, [...]"
  {:added "1.5"}
  ([coll xf]
     (reify
      clojure.core.protocols/CollReduce
      (coll-reduce [_ f1]
                   (clojure.core.protocols/coll-reduce coll (xf f1) (f1)))
   ...
```

[Christophe Grand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97592/cgrand) has a [nice post](http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2013/02/11/from-lazy-seqs-to-reducers-and-back/) on how to compose reducers in a lazy fashion.

Comment: So, I totally missed that two posts later in the same blog Christophe Grand covers this exact problem. I defer to [cgrand's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22037468/1756702) with linked post.

Answer (score 1):

Reducers do not really work well with lazy lists while normal reduce does.

To get the real benefit out of reducers you need a non-lazy collection, e.g. a vector and you need to use fold instead of reduce.

```
 (def v (into [] (range 10000000)))
 (time (reduce + (map inc v)))
 ;; "Elapsed time: 896.79 msecs"
 (time (reduce + (r/map inc v)))
 ;; "Elapsed time: 671.947 msecs" 
 (time (r/fold + (r/map inc v)))
 ;; "Elapsed time: 229.45 msecs"
```

Reducers work with the fork/join Framework which requires large chunks of data. In a lazy (chunked) sequence you do not have these large chunks, so fork/join cannot work well.

There is a talk by Rich Hickey on reducers that explain the concepts really well: https://vimeo.com/45561411

Comment: Fork/join is not applicable to r/map or r/reduce here. Also, r/reduce and normal reduce are the same.

Comment: Add another `0` to your range as in the question and you may also hit a memory error on the first line depending on your JVM settings.